# HyperX Alloy Elite 2 keyboard RGB issue

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, keyboard

I just bought the keyboard in the title. As in all Linux distros it works great without any drivers. Unfortunately as in all Linux distros there's no software to configure the RGB lighting. I tried plugging in another Windows 7 pc i have to configure it but the software is W10 or later.There is also [OpenRgb](https://github.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB) which sounds great,but their current build is broken on Arch linux which I run.I ended up reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473676/hyperx-alloy-elite-rgb-customize-led-patterns). And there one man recommends running the software in a w10 VM to configure it, which sounds great since the keyboard has an on board memory to store profiles,but the OP in the post says that plugging the keyboard in a W7 OS broke it because the firmware wasn't updated properly. I spent the whole day looking for any solutions and can't find anything that I can trust. What are my other options? I don't care about crazy lighting effects,I just want the colors to be stable instead of waving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Solved

I contacted the developers of OpenRGB and we worked a fix on their Arch build.
The software works *ok*,it has a small delay on light swiching. It has a delay when using Media keys as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your update. If possible, please add a link the OpenRGB site which mentions this fix (e.g. changelog etc.)